# Histogram from frequency data

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is already summarized in frequency form due to the substantial number of observations (N=10M).

For example, is it in the following form (df):

```
base <- data.frame(x=round(rnorm(1000,mean=100,sd=10),1))
df <- base %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(n=n())
```

How can I use this data to create a histogram in ggplot2?  I know I've done this before without manually creating the bins, but I cannot remember how for the life me.  I want to avoid re-transforming the data, ex:

```
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(rep(df$x, df$n)))
```

Thank you in advance.

edited to provide non-integer example which precludes use of geom_col/geom_bar

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x, n)) + geom_col()`. Don't use `$` inside `aes`, use the proper `data` argument instead.

Comment: @Axeman's comment seems right; i would add `width=1` so it really looks like a histogram, and not a barplot: `ggplot(df, aes(x, n)) + geom_col(width = 1)`

Comment: Thank you, but this does not handle non-integer data and does not allow me to set a binwidth.

example:


`base <- data.frame(x=round(rnorm(1000,mean=100,sd=10),1))
df <- base %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(n=n())`

Comment: If you have already created the frequencies why do you want to use a bindwidth? You should set the binwidth when you make the frequency table which you are doing using summarize().  Combining together the rows of your tibble is not something that ggplot is going to do.  Fix your x, then the rest will fall into place.

Comment: `group_by()` was intended to work on categorical variables, but in your example you feed it a continuous, real-valued variable. So, the only reason that `df` is any smaller than `base` is that you rounded `x` to 1 decimal place. This seems like a significant source of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use geom_bar.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, n)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: This does not work if the x values are not evenly distributed.  Furthermore, it cannot handle alternate binwidths.  For example:


`base <- data.frame(x=round(rnorm(1000,mean=100,sd=10),1))
df <- base %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(n=n())`